# Sitecore: How to display content from an items first child?

Tags: sitecore

Say I have a content structure like:

```
About Us
  Information
  Contact Us
  Blah
```

When a user clicks About Us, how can I make it display the Information page?

This would be required on multiple site sections so hardcoding links / redirects won't work.

How can I make a page display the content from the first child, if exists?

Comment: Are you using xslt or codebehind?

Comment: Ah, my answer doesn't apply then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it might be easier to answer if you describe what you are trying to do.

But if you are on the "About Us" page (ie. Sitecore.Context.Item is the "About Us" item).

You can check if the current item has children like this:

```
if (Sitecore.Context.Item.HasChildren) { /* do something */ }
```

You can access the children in the following way:

```
Sitecore.Context.Item.Children
```

This returns a ChildList object on which you could call GetArray() to get an Item[].

If you just blindly wanted the first item I guess you could call:

```
Sitecore.Context.Item.Children.ToArray()[0]; //arrays are zero-based, so the first item is 0 and not 1
```

But try to write a bit about what you are trying to do (ie make a menu or something).

Comment: I am trying to do this for sitewide navigation and breadcrumbs. I have implemented your suggestion but the only problem occurs if the user was to create an internal link which points to the parent object, they can still get displayed the page/item of the parent when I want it to display the first child (if it has children). Does this make sense? Any idea on how to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Hm... if what you are trying to do is the following:
every time a person goes to the "About Us" page, they get shown the info from the first child ("Information"), then I would actually just make some sublayout on the template for the "About Us" page do a redirect to the first child page. This way if a user gets onto the page somehow, they always get redirected to the child page.

It's simple (ie. easier to program) and there are fewer instances where it can fail.

Comment: Ok, yeah, that makes sense. I'll do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using xslt and 'About Us' is the context item:

```
<sc:link select="item[1]" />
```

`item` will get all items below the context (current) item, and `[1]` will choose the first.

Answer (score 2):

I have actually implemented this behavior for one of our bigger websites.

A working (works for me) way you can also do this is:

```
if (item.TemplateName.ToLower().ToString() == "main menu item")
{

    if (item.Children.Any())
    {
       url = GetItemUrl(item.Children.First<Item>());
    }
    else
    {
       url = GetItemUrl(item);
    }
}
else
{
     url = GetItemUrl(item);
}
```

In this case GetItemUrl is used to get the url, but I can imagine you using LinkManager.GetItemUrl(Item item);

Answer (score 1):

You might want to add some template checking in here, but how about this:

```
if (Sitecore.Context.Item.HasChildren) {
  var children = Sitecore.Context.Item.GetChildren();
  Response.Redirect(LinkManager.GetItemUrl(children[0]))
}
```

This will see if the current page has children and if so will redirect to that page. I actually do this on a site for a law firm that has office locations. So when you go to the main locations page, it will redirect to the first office alphabetically.